# Detect button press in samsung headsets Android

Tags: android, broadcast, headset

i'm trying to detect (via BroadcastReciever) hard pressing on original samsung headset buttons.

the code is simple:

```
public class MediaButtonIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public MediaButtonIntentReceiver() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String intentAction = intent.getAction();
    Toast.makeText(context, "Action: "+intentAction, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
        return;
    }
    Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON PRESSED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
    if (event == null) {
        return;
    }
    int action = event.getAction();
    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    // do something
        Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON PRESSED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
    abortBroadcast();
}
```

Manifest:

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".MediaButtonIntentReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="100000000000000" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

I've tested it in galaxy s1 (2 rooted devices, nothing happened) and galaxy NOTE (media was started/stopped and volume has been changed accordignly, but nothing happened from the code ..), in HTC everything worked fine.
I'm 99% sure it's not priority problem as I changed it several times.

I would appreciate if someone knows what's going on in there.
Thanks. Udi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to call [registerMediaButtonEventReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#registerMediaButtonEventReceiver%28android.app.PendingIntent%29)  on [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) in order to receive the events. That state will hold until something else calls registerMediaButtonEventReceiver() or until you call [unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver%28android.content.ComponentName%29)().

For example, an activity like this:

```
public class MediaButtonActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ((AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE)).registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(new ComponentName(
                                                                                                   this,
                                                                                                   MediaButtonIntentReceiver.class));
    }
}
```

will enable your manifest-registered MediaButtonIntentReceiver to get ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON events.

Answer (score 0):

Try Turning off S-Voice and running your application again .